# Unity profiler Physics Optimization.( Fps drop )

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, physics, profiler

hi i am developing my new game but i have some fps drop in some mobile phones ( etc one m9, iPad 3 ..

i have profiler in htc m9. Why physics.Fetchresults are big ?[image]

Comment: You should look at `FixedUpdate()`. Without code we cant tell you what's wrong.

Comment: it s about only fixed update ? or Update ,Late Update

Comment: It wasnt so hard to find `Physics.FetchResults` in Unity Docs: [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html)

Comment: one of the most common problems is that you are `Instantiate` very often all at once.   but it's absolutely impossible to help you as you gave **no information whatsoever about your game**.  you do not even mention what genre it is. you need to include a screenshot and a general outline explanation of your game and how it works

Comment: there is very little reason to use FixedUpdate in a properly engineered Unity project.  it's possible you have many basic engineering problems; it may be difficult to find "one fix"

Comment: my game is like infinite running but game have lots of character obstacle in road and they have different waypoints and animation.

Comment: Infinite running, huh? In that case, Joe's point may be very pertinent to your situation - if you're executing `Instantiate()` and `Destroy()` frequently as you approach and pass objects on the running track, that could cause significant performance drops. Look into [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling) if you haven't already.

Comment: İ am using object pooling. My characters have ragdoll and rigidbody ? İs it problem for optimization?